# Some Modes on action.devices.traits.Modes does not seem to be working

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm playing around with  action.devices.traits.Modes trait, and it seems that I cannot get some Mode to work, though I'm 100% sure that I've used mode names exactly as in the documentation.

SYNC Response:

```
Response {
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "body": {
    "requestId": "15896565509066911859",
    "payload": {
      "agentUserId": "",
      "devices": [
        {
          "id": "Washer",
          "type": "action.devices.types.WASHER",
          "traits": [
            "action.devices.traits.Modes",
            "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
          ],
          "name": {
            "defaultNames": [
              "Washer"
            ],
            "name": "Washer",
            "nicknames": [
              "Washer"
            ]
          },
          "willReportState": false,
          "customData": {
            "lookupOnExecute": true
          },
          "attributes": {
            "availableModes": [
              {
                "name": "temperature",
                "name_values": [
                  {
                    "name_synonym": [
                      "temperature"
                    ],
                    "lang": "en"
                  }
                ],
                "settings": [
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Tap Cold",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "tap cold"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Cold Warm",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "cold warm"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Hot",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "hot"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Extra Hot",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "extra hot"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "ordered": false
              },
              {
                "name": "Cycle",
                "name_values": [
                  {
                    "name_synonym": [
                      "cycle"
                    ],
                    "lang": "en"
                  }
                ],
                "settings": [
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Low",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "low"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "Medium",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "medium"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "setting_name": "High",
                    "setting_values": [
                      {
                        "setting_synonym": [
                          "high"
                        ],
                        "lang": "en"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "ordered": false
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

QUERY response:

```
Response {
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "body": {
    "requestId": "17335788264128789760",
    "payload": {
      "devices": {
        "Washer": {
          "online": true,
          "currentModeSettings": {
            "Cycle": "High",
            "temperature": "Tap Cold"
          },
          "on": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why does Cycle query fail? I see `Cycle` mode in the documentation. Does it support only some settings? Does the case matter? `High` is also available, so what am I doing wrong?

And Interaction with Google Home:

[image: Google Home Interaction]

Comment: Can you confirm whether your integration also reports these values via Report State, or whether they are only sent in response to a QUERY?

Comment: @Devunwired only sent in response to a QUERY

Comment: This may be related to an issue in the grammar triggering the right intent. Can you try using a more strict request "What is the <device> <mode>?". In this case, use the exact query "What is the washer cycle?"

Comment: @Devunwired yep, that worked. Thank you. I'm not an native English speaker, is the question "What Cycle is the Washer On" not grammatically correct? And since we are here how can I combine Two toggles (Bluetooth and Power Saving) into one trigger? E.g. "Turn on Power Saving and Bluetooth on Home Cinema?"

Comment: Please file an issue in the public issue track. Since it works with one of your modes but not the other there is something in the grammar that needs to be investigated further. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148

Answer (score 0):

While the Google Assistant is highly capable of detecting variations in speech while receiving voice commands, it is still a good practice to make the grammar more understandable and as mentioned in the comments. This is related to an issue in the usage of grammar while triggering the right intent, since a change in the way the question was asked solved the purpose.

For the answer to the question "how can I combine Two toggles (Bluetooth and Power Saving) into one trigger – e.g. "Turn on Power Saving and Bluetooth on Home Cinema?" asked in the comments – at the moment Smart Home doesn't allow two commands in a single prompt. For example, you cannot say "Hey Google, turn on my light and change the color". In order to do that you have to execute each command separately.